# how to create pairwise table based on a column for division between element in r

Tags: r

I a data frame (d) which I want to do a pairwise division between element in column %

```
> d

x %
a 3
b 10
c 5
```

I want to do a pairwise this

```
     3  |5   |10
a 3 |1  |0.6 |0.3
b 5 |1.7|1   |2
c 10|3.3|2   |1
```

thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `outer`

```
outer(d$`%`, d$`%`, `/`)
```

We can add row and column names to it.

```
matrix(outer(d$`%`, d$`%`, `/`), nrow(d), dimnames = list(d$`%`, d$`%`))

#      3  10   5
#3  1.00 0.3 0.6
#10 3.33 1.0 2.0
#5  1.67 0.5 1.0
```

**data**

```
d <- structure(list(x = structure(1:3, .Label = c("a", "b", "c"), class = "factor"),
`%` = c(3L, 10L, 5L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `tidyverse` functions

```
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
expand(d, col1 = `%`, col2 = `%`) %>% 
     mutate(new = col1/col2) %>%
     pivot_wider(names_from = col2, values_from = new) %>% 
     column_to_rownames('col1')
#         3   5  10
#3  1.000000 0.6 0.3
#5  1.666667 1.0 0.5
#10 3.333333 2.0 1.0
```

#### data

```
d <- structure(list(x = structure(1:3, .Label = c("a", "b", "c"), class = "factor"), 
    `%` = c(3L, 10L, 5L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```